# Haskell Matrix appears to not be calling Num instance

Tags: haskell, matrix

I am trying to multiply 2x2 matrices as a learning exercise. I am trying to make my `Matrix` type an instance of `Num` so I can multiply with `*`. When I attempt to execute `(Matrix 1 2 3 4) *(Matrix 1 1 1 1)` in GHCI, I get an error that says use `FlexibleContexts to permit this` even though I am using Flexible contexts:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import Debug.Trace
data Matrix a b c d= Matrix a b c d
    deriving (Show)

instance Num a=>Num (Matrix a a a a) where
    (*) (Matrix a1 b1 c1 d1) (Matrix a2 b2 c2 d2) =  (trace "* ran")(Matrix (a1*a2 + b1*c2) (a1*b2 + b1*d2) (c1*a2 + d1*c2) (c1*b2+d2*d1))

multMat (Matrix a1 b1 c1 d1) (Matrix a2 b2 c2 d2) =  (trace "Multmat ran")(Matrix (a1*a2 + b1*c2) (a1*b2 + b1*d2) (c1*a2 + d1*c2) (c1*b2 + d1*d2))
```

I don't think my `*` method is being called as the `"* ran"` never prints out. On the other hand, if I run multMat (which is the same code, except for the function name) the debug statement prints and I get the expected answer.

***I think the problem is that when is use `*` on Matrix data types, some other method is being called. How can I make it call my method? ***

While this code compiles, it gives a runtime error on attempts to use `*` type `Matrix`.

Comment: What if you remove the `FlexibleInstances` and `FlexibleContexts`. I do not get your reported compiler output. It works fine for me.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem If I remove `FlexibleInstances`, I can't compile as I get an `IllegalInstanceDeclaration` on the instance `Num a` line. I am using version `7.10.2`.

Comment: sorry, you indeed need these. Nevertheless I am unable to reproduce the error. It works just fine.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Can you reproduce the error if you try to run the code e.g. `(Matrix 1 2 3 4) *(Matrix 1 1 1 1)` ?

Comment: Why would you parameterise `Matrix` on _four possibly different_ types? That completely contradicts the concept of a matrix (a _homogeneous_ 2D-array, representing linear mappings between vector spaces _over a single field_).

Comment: @leftaroundabout I am still learning Haskell. I thought that by specifying `Matrix a a a a` in the instance declaration I was saying that all of the parameters should be the same number. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @fdsa but why have the four different types in the first place?  Why not write `data Matrix a = Matrix a a a a`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition for your matrix multiplication is fine (although semantically it is not correct). Your code compiles well. The problem is however that if you perform a query:

```
*Main> (Matrix 1 2 3 4) * (Matrix 7 5 3 1)
```

Haskell is confused which type it should attach to `1`, `2`, etc. It could be `Int`, `Integer`, `Float`, `Double`, etc. and all these have different implementations (if it picks `Float`, it will perform a *floating point multiplication*, which is different from an *integer multiplication*).

The solution is that you give Haskell a hint which type you are using:

```
*Main> (Matrix (1 :: Int) (2 :: Int) (3 :: Int) (4 :: Int)) * (Matrix (7 :: Int) (5 :: Int) (3 :: Int) (1 :: Int))
Matrix 7 6 15 4
```

After all, `1` **can be any kind of `Num` type** (even a matrix), internally Haskell will call `fromInteger` to convert it to the correct `Num` type.

That's also the reason why instantiating a `Matrix` from `Num` is not straightforward: you need to convert an integer to a matrix. Since your `Matrix` datatype only allows 2 x 2 matrices, there is no straightforward way of doing so.

A final note is that your matrix multiplication is wrong. You should use:

```
instance Num a=>Num (Matrix a a a a) where
    (*) (Matrix a1 b1 c1 d1) (Matrix a2 b2 c2 d2) = Matrix (a1*a2+b1*c2) (a1*b2+b1*d2) (c1*a2+d1*c2) (b2*c1+d1*d2)
```

although I can understand this is only a simple test.

## Additional notes

[In the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733374/haskell-matrix-appears-to-not-be-calling-num-instance/34733434?noredirect=1#comment57214838_34733434), @stites asked an interesting question of whether it would be sufficient to instantiate only one of the Matrix types. Something like:

```
(Matrix (1 :: Int) 2 3 4) * (Matrix 7 5 3 1)
```

Haskell however errors on this, and that is reasonable. After all, a valid way of reasoning about this, is that you can still intend to use:

```
Matrix Int Float Float Int
```

Now you only defined an `instance` for `Matrix a a a a`, but it would be possible *to define an additional one*, like:

```
instance Num (Matrix Int Float Float Int) where
    (*) ...
```

since a compiler should be *conservative*, it cannot *simply assume* the most popular `instance` is selected: perhaps you are under the impression that you have defined another instance somewhere.

Additionally when you fully specify the type of the left matrix, it works:

```
*Main> (Matrix (1 :: Int) (2 :: Int) (3 :: Int) (4 :: Int)) * (Matrix 7 5 3 1)
Matrix 7 6 15 4
```

This is because now you have fully specified the left operand being of the type `Matrix Int Int Int Int`. Since `(*)` has the signature:

```
(*) :: Num e => e -> e -> e
```

(used `e` to reduce confusion), it knows that `e = Matrix Int Int Int Int` so it can "collapse" the right operand: it can thus derive the right operand is of type `Matrix Int Int Int Int` as well.

You can even specify the types at arbitrary sides, for instance:

```
*Main> (Matrix (1 :: Int) 2 (3 :: Int) 4) * (Matrix 7 (5 :: Int) 3 (1 :: Int))
Matrix 7 6 15 4
```

works as well. Because first Haskell derives that `e = Matrix a b c d`. Now the first operand fills in `a = Int`, the second `b = Int`, etc.

@user2407038 also provides a useful [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733374/haskell-matrix-appears-to-not-be-calling-num-instance/34733434?noredirect=1#comment57232283_34733434). You can also write your defintion as:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

-- ...

instance (Num a, a ~ b, b ~ c, c ~ d) => Num (Matrix a b c d) where
    (*) (Matrix a1 b1 c1 d1) (Matrix a2 b2 c2 d2) = Matrix (a1*a2+b1*c2) (a1*b2+b1*d2) (c1*a2+d1*c2) (b2*c1+d1*d2)
```

Since the signature says `Matrix a b c d`, Haskell will try to match the multipication with this instance. And it can do so if `(Num a, a ~ b, b ~ c, c ~ d)`. Which is true.

Comment: I should have been more clear in my question. The code will compile but it errors when I actually try to perform a multiplication

Comment: A point from the peanut gallery: wouldn't it be possible to simplify the typings in your example of (Matrix (1 :: Int) ...? You should be able to get away with just one explicit type and ghci will infer the rest. Doesn't change the answer, but perhaps it's worth noting.

Comment: @stites: No. This won't work: note that you only specified an instance for `Matrix a a a a`. This means that the `instance` for `Matrix Int Float Int Float` is still open for additional specification. You can however limit yourself to specifying the left `Matrix`: `(Matrix (1 :: Int) (2 :: Int) (3 :: Int) (4 :: Int)) * (Matrix 7 5 3 1)` works, because Haskell knows that a `(*)` is always define on the same types left and right.

Comment: @stites: I found your comment quite valuable, I've added a note in the answer that should explain the situation.

Comment: You will get the most out of type inference if you write the instance as `instance (Num a, a ~ b, b ~ c, c ~ d) => Num (Matrix a b c d) where ...` - in this case these expressions should compile without additional type annotations.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem — great explanation! Thanks for this!